# Updating a table with in clause Error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE
  TABLE1 a,
  TABLE2 b
SET
  a.COL1 = 'VALUE'
WHERE
  a.FK = b.PK
  AND b.COL2 IN ('A subquery')
```

If I am using this update statement and the subquery in the IN clause does not return any rows, I get an error. How do I avoid that? (Oracle 10g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely can rewrite this to an EXISTS query, depending on the exact details of your subquery:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b SET a.COL1 = 'VALUE' 
WHERE a.FK = b.PK AND EXISTS (select 1 from OTHERTABLE O where B.COL2=O.COL2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
  TABLE1 a
SET
  a.COL1 = 'VALUE'
WHERE
  a.FK IN (SELECT b.PK FROM b WHERE b.COL2 in ....)
```

Comment: Don't forget the `a.FK = b.PK` here - that has to be added to your subquery

Comment: I think the question was implying that `'A subquery'` is actually a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is your subquery in quotes?

```
UPDATE
  TABLE1 a,
  TABLE2 b
SET
  a.COL1 = value
WHERE
  a.FK = b.PK
  AND b.COL2 IN (
                 SELECT col2
                 FROM ...
                 WHERE ...
                )
```